# CSS Keep div at a fixed width when minimizing screen

Tags: html, css

Hello guys  have a div that is outside of a table and I want the div to stay the same size when a user minimizes the screen.  Here is what its doing:

Basically i want the width to stay at 60% and not shrink when I minimize the page:

CSS:

```
message_box,

{
background-color:#EEEECC;
border: #CCCCAA thin solid;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 5px;
text-align: center;
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 10pt;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="message_box" style="width: 60%">
```

Comment: What do you mean by "minimizes the screen"?

Comment: 60% of what? Is it in a wrapper div of some sort? Also you forgot a `.` before `message_box`.

Comment: Can you give more detail? Why do you want to control the styles if the window is minimised?

Comment: sorry for the lack of info fellas...yeah the screen was being resized

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you set an element to `width:60%`, that means that the element will be 60% as wide as its parent element.

If `<div class="message_box">`’s parent element gets narrower, then `<div class="message_box">` will get narrower too.

When you say you want `<div class="message_box">` to be 60% wide, what exactly do you mean? 60% of what?

If you’d like `<div class="message_box">`’s width to be a specific number of pixels, and not change when the user resizes their browser window, you should set its width in pixels, e.g.:

```
<div class="message_box" style="width: 300px">
```

Comment: This worked...I set it to 900px and the div stayed at a static size

Comment: @DocHoliday You should rephrase your question if this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that by "minimize" you mean that when the user resizes the window, you want the div to stay at 60% of its parent element. In this case something like this should work:

```
.message_box{
    background-color:#EEEECC;
    border: #CCCCAA thin solid;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:60%;
}
```

If the div has a parent element, make sure this element has a width set and it is has the css attribute  `position:relative`

Answer (score 0):

You should keep it static, assign the value in pixels, 600px (or whatever the size you want).